# JavaScript: Is there a better way to construct an object from query strings of a url

Tags: javascript, html

I have a url string like this `"http://url.com/foo/aa=342&bb=66"`
and I need to construct an object from it

```js
{ aa: '342', bb: '66' }
```

Here is my attempt

```js
function constructFromUrl(url) {
    return url.split('/').at(-1).split('&').reduce((accu, curr) => {
        const [key, value] = curr.split('=')
        accu[key] = value
        return accu
    },{})
}
```

It works ok but I feel like it is really brittle. Is there any better way of handling this?

Also, I am really bad at naming things - is there a better name for such a function?

Comment: Are you sure this URL is correct? Shouldn't there be a `?` before the query part? If there were, you could simply use `Object.fromEntries(new URL(urlString).searchParams)` without the whole splitting and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const getQueryParams = (urlStr) => Object.fromEntries([
    ...new URL(urlStr).searchParams
])
```

Note however that this will fail for your example URL string, because it's malformed — the query string must be separated with a `?`, like this:

`http://url.com/foo/?aa=342&bb=66`

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the parameters with the [`URLSearchParams` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams), then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries):

```js
const url = "http://url.com/foo/aa=342&bb=66"
const params = url.split("/").slice(-1)[0]
const result = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(params))

console.log('params:', params)
console.log(result)
```